# Python / Django - Exception Value: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Meta'

Tags: python, django, httprequest, middleware

I am willing to save all the http requests to the database (request_method stands for db field) and print them out to the page (for example, last 10 requests) but am getting the following problem: Exception Value: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Meta'.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

    class HttpRequest(models.Model):

        time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
        request_method = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

**middleware.py**

```
from .models import HttpRequest

class FirstMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        data = HttpRequest(request_method=request.Meta['REQUEST_METHOD'])
        data.save()
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def view_requests(request):
    request_list = HttpRequest.objects.all()[:10]
    return render(request, 'apps/hello/request_list', {'list': request_list})
```

This problem occurs during the processing of the middleware.py file (that's why am not sure that view.py is needed here but why not:)) and due to I am a complete beginner in django, it makes a great challenge to fix it by myself, though the task seems to be pretty easy. Would be really glad for you insights.

Comment: HttpRequest is a built-in class in django.http. You may want to rename your custom class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not `Meta`. It's `META`. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Oh. Thanks..) A great example of inadvertence)